# Apache Kafka: kafka.common.OffsetsOutOfOrderException when reassigning __consumer_offsets to new brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

we have upgraded Kafka from 2.2 to 2.6, and added 4 new brokers to the existing 4 brokers. This went fine.

After that we started to reassign topic data to the new brokers. Most topics went ok, but on one of the 50 partitions of __consumer_offsets, the reassignment hangs. 49 of the partitions were successfully moved from the old brokers (id 3,4,5,6) to the new (ids 10,11,12,13).

But on __consumer_offsets-18 we consistently get this error (in the server.log of the new brokers)

```
[2020-10-24 15:04:54,528] ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=10, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Unexpected error occurred while processing data for partition __consumer_offsets-18 at offset 1545264631 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
kafka.common.OffsetsOutOfOrderException: Out of order offsets found in append to __consumer_offsets-18: ArrayBuffer(1545264631, 1545264632, 
... thousands of other ids
1545272005, 1545272006, 1545272007)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$append$2(Log.scala:1126)
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:2340)
    at kafka.log.Log.appendAsFollower(Log.scala:1036)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.doAppendRecordsToFollowerOrFutureReplica(Partition.scala:939)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.appendRecordsToFollowerOrFutureReplica(Partition.scala:946)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.processPartitionData(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:168)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$processFetchRequest$7(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:332)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$processFetchRequest$6(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:320)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$processFetchRequest$6$adapted(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:319)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:319)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:135)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:134)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:117)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
[2020-10-24 15:04:54,534] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=10, leaderId=4, fetcherId=0] Truncating partition __consumer_offsets-31 to local high watermark 0 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2020-10-24 15:04:54,547] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=10, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Partition __consumer_offsets-18 marked as failed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

Any idea what is wrong here? The whole cluster seems to process data nicely. It's just that we can't move over this particular partition. We tried various things (cancelling the reassignment, restarting it with all partitions, restarting it with just partition 18, restarting all brokers) to no avail

Help very much appreciated, this is happening in PROD only after it worked successfully on all test environments.

EDIT: we actually found that in the huge list of message offsets in the list of the exception, there is actually a descrepancy. The relevant part of this list is

```
... 1545271418, 1545271419, 1, 1, 1545271422, 1545271423,
```

Obviously the two '1' entries there look really wrong! They should be 1545271420/1545271421. Could it be that the leader really has some kind of data corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were ultimately able to solve this issue - mainly by sitting and waiting

The issue was indeed that somewhen, somehow, the data on the leader of this __consumer_offset-18 partition got corrupted. This probably happened during the upgrade from Kafka 2.2 -> 2.6. We were doing this in a rather dangerous way, as we know now: we simply stopped all brokers, updated the SW on all, and restarted them. We thought since we can afford this outage on the weekend, this would be a safe way. But we will certainly never do that again. At least not unless we know 100% that all producers and all consumers are really stopped.  This was NOT the case during that upgrade, we overlooked one consumer and left that running, and that consumer (group) was storing their offsets in the __consumer_offset-18 partition. So that action - taking all brokers down and upgrade them - while consumers/producers are still running, did probably cause the corruption

Lesson learnt: never do that again, always do rolling upgrades, even if they take a lot longer.

The issue was then actually solved through the nature of the compacting topic. The default settings for compaction are to run it every week (or when a segment gets bigger than 1GB, which will not happen in our case). Compaction of that __consumer_offset-18 partition kicked in yesterday evening. And by that the 2 corrupted offsets were purged away. After that it was uphill, the reassign of that partition to the new brokers then worked like a charm.

We could certainly have speeded up this recovery by setting the topic parameters in a way that compaction would kick in earlier. But it was only on Wednesday when we reached the understanding that the problem could actually be resolved that way. We decided to leave everything as it was and wait another day.

Comment: We are facing exactly same situation after we moved to a clean new Kafka 2.6. Apart from this thread, there is absolutely no other mention of `OffsetsOutOfOrderException` anywhere else on the internet. Could you provide some insight to fix this issue. Unsure how to force compaction as explained in your answer. In my cases, there are 8-10 partitions reporting this in the `__consumer_offset` topic. However, the kafka ingestion is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, missed this notification. Our understanding of the situation was that the data was really corrupted and could not be fixed with any procedure. So the only way to get rid of these corrupted segments and get back to a fully replicated situation was to make sure the corrupted data was expired. We did this by waiting a week (default retention.ms a 7 days)

Comment: You can probably speed this up by reducing retention.ms on __consumer_offset to a lower time (but enough to keep your latest consumer group offsets valid)

Comment: Thanks @jammann. We moved to kafka 2.2 instead of 2.6 and 2.2 is working fine. We could not fix the issue in 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I encountered the same problem.
[image]

Partition __consumer_offsets-47, leader is node1, follower is node0. Data on node0 cannot be synchronized, and an exception is thrown on node0:

kafkaServer.out: kafka.common.OffsetsOutOfOrderException: Out of order offsets found in append to __consumer_offsets-47: List(457437420, 457437421, 457437422, 457437423, 457437424, 457437425, 457437426, 457437427, 457437428, 457437429, 457437430, 457437431, 457437432, 457437433, 457437434, 457437435, 457437436, 457437437, 457437438, 457437439, 457437440, 457437441, 457437442, 457437443, 457437444, 457437445, 457437446, 457437447, 457437448, 457437449, 457437450, 45

The cleanup policy for __consumer_offsets is compact.

I encountered this issue, and the compact policy cannot remove the corrupted data (the corrupted data is in active segments). Just as the delete policy doesn't remove the current active segment, the compact policy doesn't compact the current active segment; it only compacts messages in older segments.

As I have already waited for two days, this issue cannot be auto-corrected.

Previously, I attempted to manually delete partition data to address this issue, which was effective. However, this method carries some risk and requires a broker restart. The steps for this operation are as follows:

1. Stopping a broker.
2. Deleting the relevant data.
   rm -rf /mnt/kafka-logs-new/__consumer_offsets-6/*

deleteall /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets/partitions/6

3. Starting the broker again.

At this point, the deleted partitions would be automatically recreated, but their leader became negative. There was no automatic creation of related partition data in Zookeeper. This caused some anxiety as I didn't know where the problem lay.
Then, something magical happened: another broker went down, triggering a leader re-election. Suddenly, everything returned to normal.
Therefore, if you intend to delete the __consumer_offsets topic and encounter unexpected results, try restarting other brokers to allow the cluster to perform a leader election. This might resolve the issue."

Comment: https://medium.com/@nblaye/reset-consumer-offsets-topic-in-kafka-with-zookeeper-5910213284a2